# XSLT list item position issue

Tags: xslt

pls check the below code. I am matching the list element and as per the below code the position() function returns correct number of the element with in ul elements i.e 1,2,3 where as if i do the test with position i get only ss,ss,ss . Can anyone let me know where am missing ?

XSL-FO

```
<xsl:template match="html:li" priority="2">
    <fo:list-item>
       ...
       <xsl:value-of select="position()"/> -- this returns 1,2,3
       <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:text>ss</xsl:text> -- only executes 
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 2">
        <xsl:text>ssddddd</xsl:text> -- does not only execute
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 3">
        <xsl:text>sskkkkkkkkk</xsl:text> -- does not only execute
      </xsl:if> 
    </fo:list-item>
</xsl:template
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:if test="list.item">
        <xsl:variable name="styleAttr">             
            <xsl:text>margin-top: 1em;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>

        <div>
            <xsl:if test="string-length($styleAttr) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$styleAttr"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>

            <ul>                    
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::list)]" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list.item" priority="1">
    <li style="padding: 0;">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][self::list]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" />
            </xsl:if>
        </div>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please show the whole XSLT file.

Comment: Not the *whole* file, just enough code (XML + XSLT) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ michael.hor the xml is nothing special but the list of li elements. This XML is transformed into FO. Is this information sufficient ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMT

Comment: And @michael.hor257k example is a perfect reason why you need more of the XSL. If you take his example and remove the strip-space and the template match on ul you will get a completely different answer.

Comment: @KevinBrown But OP says that position() does return 1, 2, 3. That would not be the case if there were other nodes included in the count, as you suggest.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated the XSL with the actual code...Now can you please help me why am seeing that wierd behaviour?

Comment: @user3496151 If you don't post code that I can run *as is* just by copy-and-paste then no, I will not help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @michael.hor257k can you tell me how to find the position of the li element outside the context...so in this case i am matching against each li element correct.I need a way to get the position of the li element within the ul (parent)element.

Comment: There is no such thing as a position outside of context.